# jQuery value exists in array

Tags: jquery, arrays, contains, exists

I work on a contact form in HTML, PHP and jQuery.

Recently, I try to secure the entire form and, to realise this, I use an array  like this :

```
var parameters = [
        {
            'format': 'email',
            'value': 'bernard.dupont@yahoo.fr'
        },
        {
            'format': 'subject',
            'value': 'Hello world'
        },
        {
            'format': 'message',
            'value': 'Good morning !'
        }
    ]`
```

Here is my code :

```
function verificationInput(array, format, param, field, length) {
    var test = verificationFormat(format, param, length);

    if (!test) {
        $('#' + field).removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid');
    } else {
        $('#' + field).removeClass('invalid').addClass('valid');
    }

    var added=false;
    $.map(array, function(key, item) {
        if (item.value == param) {
            item.value = param;
            added = true;
        }
    });
    if (!added) {
        array.push({format: format, value: param});
    }
}
```

The idea is to change the value if the format is present and the value if it is present.

Comment: try to create a https://jsfiddle.net/ to clarify your question

Comment: Is there any relationship between `array` and `parameters`?

Comment: I have just updated the question :)

Comment: What is the sense in doing this: `if (item.value == param) {
        item.value = param;`. That seems useless. Are you sure you want to compare the value, and not the format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use a data structure that is keyed by the format? It would be much easier to work with:

```
var parameters = {
    email: 'bernard.dupont@yahoo.fr',
    subject: 'Hello world',
    message: 'Good morning !'
};
```

Then your code could look like this:

```
parameters[format] = param;
```

This will add the format if not already present, and otherwise update the value associated with that format.

If you ever need to iterate over the parameters, you can still use `$.map`.